# Many-to-many relationship, update referenced Set (update join table) throw NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am using hibernate. I have a **Many-to-Many** relationship between `Student` and `Group` classes. There is a **join table** named `student_group` which has `student_id` and `group_id` columns.

`Student` **class:**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "student")
    public class Student {
      private int student_id; //primary key

      @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students")
      private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>();

      @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
      @JoinTable(name="student_group",
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="student_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="group_id")})
      public Set<Group> getGroups() {
        return groups;
      }

      public void setGroups(Set<Group> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
      }

      //Setter & Getter for student_id
      ...
    }
```

`Group` **class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class Group {
  private int group_id;//primary key
  private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();

  @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinTable(name="student_group",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="group_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="student_id")})
  public Set<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
  }

  public void setStudents(Set<Student> students) {
    this.students = students;
  }

  //Getter & Setting for group_id
  ...

}
```

In my main program I have a function which **1st find a** `student` **from database**, then, **add a** `group` **to the** `student` and **finally try to save the updated** `student` **to database:**

```
public void addGroupToStudent(int studentId, Group newGroup){
   //open a session & query the database to get a student by id
   Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
   Student student = loadStudentById(session, id);

   //Get above student's groups
   Set<Group> groups = student.getGroups();

  //Add the new group
  groups.add(newGroup);

  //SaveAndUpdate the student in database
  Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
  try {
    session.saveOrUpdate(student);
    transaction.commit();
  } catch (final HibernateException e) {...}

}
```

(The `newGroup` parameter in above function is retrieved from database with **another** session & query.)

But the above function throw the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.my.db.Group#5]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:697)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
```

**Where am I wrong? How to get rid of this exception?** Generally I just want to update a student's groups in database, which in turns should update the join table.

Comment: Can you tell the state for that `newGroup`? New/transient? Managed? Detached?

Comment: The newGroup is retrieved from database with another session & query

Comment: Hm, if it is from another session, then it is detached to the current session (the one you are trying to save it to). Try merging it before saving the student (that is, add a `session.merge(newGroup);` before the `session.saveOrUpdate(student);` line).

Comment: Hi, I tried 1st merge then saveOrUpdate, the exception is disappeared, but the join table is not updated, I mean in database, the newGroup's group_id is not in the join table with student_id

Comment: Maybe this is happening because you also have to add the student to the group's students set. Like `newGroup.getStudents().add(student);` nearby `groups.add(newGroup);`. Can you try if this works? (Though I'm unsure if, even if it does work, maybe there is a simpler way, like an annotation or something else that would do this "double-reference" adding, if you know what I mean.)